# Multiple graphQL client endpoints in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql, graphql-java

In my project I need to fetch data from multiple graphql endpoints.
I defined one in my application.properties file like so:
`graphql.client.url=https://api.foo.com/graphql-1`
and fetching data in code:

```
public Foo getFooByid(String id) throws Exception {
    final GraphQLRequest request =
        GraphQLRequest.builder()
            .query(orgByIdQuery)
            .variables(Map.of("id", id))
            .build();

    final GraphQLResponse response = graphQLWebClient.post(request).block();
    response.validateNoErrors();

    return response.get("Foo", Foo.class);

  }
```

So there is some magic that gets client url from application.properties file. Now, how can I have second client url `https://api.foo.com/graphql-2` defined and used in my code?
Dependency for gql:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.graphql-java-kickstart</groupId>
      <artifactId>graphql-webclient-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have defined all the URLs you want (with a @Value tied to your properties file), you should create a HttpGraphQlClient Bean, which you can then mutate for each request:

```
@Bean
HttpGraphQlClient graphQlClient(){
    return HttpGraphQlClient.builder()
            .url(firstUrl)
            .build();
}
```

Inside your other Component you make your first request...

```
graphQlClient
            .documentName(orgByIdQuery)
            .retrieve("org") 
            ... //etc
```

Then you  can modify it as many times as you want

```
graphQlClient
            .mutate()
            .header("Authorization","Basic anVsaW86YHIJ0ZUJBMjAyMg==") //many different customizations are allowed
            .url(anotherUrl)
            .build()
            .documentName(orgByIdQuery)
            .retrieve("org") 
            ... //etc
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

[Lib](https://github.com/graphql-java-kickstart/graphql-spring-webclient) seems to allow configuration via props for 1 client. Other clients seems has to be created programmatically.

Then either placed into spring context or used internally in class. Please see `WebClientAutoConfiguration` which provide `WebClient.Builder` and customizers for produced `WebClient`. It may be possible to reuse `WebClient.Builder`, which is already in spring context and set another baseUrl, but create new builder and configure it seems as better approach. Possible example:

```
@Component
class GqlService(
    objectMapper: ObjectMapper,
    customizerProvider: ObjectProvider<WebClientCustomizer>,
    @Value("\$graphql.client2.url") baseUrl: String
) {
    private val secondGqlClient: GraphQLWebClient
    
    init {
        val builder = WebClient.builder()
        customizerProvider.orderedStream().forEach { customizer -> customizer.customize(builder) }
        builder.baseUrl(baseUrl)
        secondGqlClient = GraphQLWebClient.newInstance(builder.build(), objectMapper)
    }
}
```